# Can't get search results on Google anymore

Tags: google-search, google-account

Since this morning, it appears that I can't get any search results anymore when I am logged in my account. If search anything, all I will get is "did not match any results". The only thing I eventually get is when my search query matches some Google Places (shops, business, ...).

I am using Google Search in a traditional way, not programatically. All the other Google services I am using work fine: calendar, mail, keep, maps, ...

When I log out, everything works fine too. I did a security check on my account and nothing particular showed up. I am pretty stuck here, any clues on how to solve this would be appreciated, thanks !

**EDIT**: it doesn't work regardless of the device I use: chrome, firefox, mobile phone... As long as I am logged in my account, I dont' get any results

Comment: Please try a different browser, and report back what the result is, the browser originally used, and the second browser used. Please click on [edit] when you report back, as comments can get shoved offscreen when new commants arrive.

Comment: I have edited my post: I don't get any results whatever the device / browser I am using